# Why is 妈妈现在有问题 a correct statement based on 妈妈很热情，总是帮助人，所以大家有问题，都会来找她

Tags: hsk

This is an example from hsk 3 mock test, you have to say whether a statement is true or false based on a statement above.
I put "False" as an answer, but this is incorrect, reference asnwers put "True" here and I've got no clue as to why.

Can you help me out? Is there some hidden meaning here?

Comment: The two statements have no causal relationship. They can happen independently of each other. What is the full question? (if making a reasonable sentence is the goal, then it is a legit choice)

Comment: @TangHo decide whether the statement is true or false based on what you hear. What is being said is the second part of my original question, the statement is the first part.  I thought it was false, while it is in fact true.

Comment: The statement cannot be 真或假 (factually true or false), it can be 正確或不正確 (grammatically correct or incorrect)

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are saying that the question asks if the sentence "妈妈现在有问题" can be inferred from "妈妈很热情，总是帮助人，所以大家有问题，都会来找她". If that is the case, then no, I do not think it can be. But do let us know the complete question so we can be more helpful.

Comment: I'm with you, it definitely is false. Can you share please which test you are referring to (such as HSK3 - H31330, for example)?

Comment: @TangHo Hi, there is no other question. Just those two sentences, one heard (妈妈很热情，总是帮助人，所以大家有问题，都会来找她) and the other written on the exam paper. It's only about content, not about grammar correctness. You have to tell if **what** is written is true based on **what** is listened. Example: (heard) 今天我想早点儿回家。看了看手表，才5点。过了一会儿再看表，还是5 点，我这才发现我的手表不走了。(written) 那块儿手表不是他的。What is written is to be marked with a big X. This is how HSK 听力考试 works.

Comment: So, the correct answer to your example is "False"? :)

Comment: BTW, my view is the correct answer for OP's question is "True"

Comment: Let's ask OP's question in English  --  "Mother is very kind, constantly helping people, therefore everyone with problems would come to look for her" Answer:- "Mother now has problems" The question is, is the Answer a "True" or "False" comment / statement on the question?

Comment: I believe the question is to test students' understanding of what 有问题 means in the context of the "overheard" statement. Also to differentiate between 问题 & 有问题, the former means "question", or just "problems", and the latter in a certain context means "have problems" Mother did not have "questions", 问题, but she "had problems", 有问题, meaning she is suffering from some mental stress or distress due to having to constantly solve numerous other people's problems, 问题.

Comment: The fact that we're having this discussion means that it is a bad question, regardless what the "right" answer is.

Comment: @WayneCheah Yes, it is False. What I wrote is one of the two examples given at each HSK3. The terms "True" or "False" are not even used, just "√" and "X". The other example is: 为了让自己更健康，他每天都花一个小时去锻炼身体。 ★  他希望自己很健康。（  √ ）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some HSK mock exams (those written by an author unaffiliated with Hanban) are mediocre quality. I remember encountering this fill-in-the-blanks question on a HSK6 mock exam:

> [image: photo of mock HSK6 question]

There are 5 blanks, and 4 words you can fill in the blanks with.  It's impossible!  Just learn what you can learn from the mock exams, and move on.

The statement

> 妈妈很热情，总是帮助人，所以大家有问题，都会来找她。

likely means what you think it means:

> Mother is warm-hearted, and always helps people.  So when anyone has a problem, they come find her.

So is 妈妈现在有问题 true or false?

1. False, the snippet does not directly imply this.  (The given answer is incorrect.)
2. True, mother always has people asking her for help.

Both answers are possible depending on your point of view.  I (like the OP) think the most natural answer is "false" (it's 大家有问题 not 妈妈有问题), but who knows what the author was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

"妈妈现在有问题" is imperfect, but an acceptable and Grammatically correct, statement.

For example - A mother was unusually quiet and irresponsive to her child's nagging demand, the child then objected: "What's wrong with you, why ignore me? 多丟人,我朋友還在吶!". The mother may respond: "妈妈现在有问题.別打擾." or "妈妈现在有问题(要處理),沒時間答理你." THe child then explained to his/her friend to get himself/herself out of embarrassment (for being ignored/brushed off): "妈妈很热情，总是帮助人，所以大家有问题，都会来找她, 她现在是问题纏身,分神乏術."